# examples of a special problem in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem asks to find out examples of two distinct linear transformations $T$ and $S$ (say) from vector spaces $V$ to $W$ so that $ker(T)=ker(S)$ and $Im(T)=Im(S)$.

I have given an example from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ where $T(x,y)=(y,x)$ and another is identity transformation.But I want to have examples where domain space and co-domain space are different (maybe of different dimensions). Also my point is to know if there are any transformations existing in  general spaces i.e from $V$ to $W$.

Any help in this regard is welcome.

Comment: How do you define "distinct"? Does $T=2S$ already count as distinct?

Comment: yes they will be considered as distinct but they are not serving our purpose.and my definition of being distinct is that  their rule of correspondence has to be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic recipe to create such pairs of linear transformations:

1. Select a vector space $X$ so that $\dim X\le\min(\dim V, \dim W)$, but otherwise arbitrary.
2. Choose an arbitrary surjective linear transformation $A:V\to X$.
3. Choose two arbitrary, but different bijective linear transformations $B_1$ and $B_2$ from $X$ to itself.
4. Choose an arbitrary injective linear transformation $C:X\to W$.

Then $S = CB_1A$ and $T=CB_2A$.

Basically, $A$ determines the kernel, $C$ determines the image, and $B_1$ and $B_2$ then determine which of the linear transformations with the given kernel and image are chosen.

For example, assume $V=\mathbb R^4$ and $W=\mathbb R^3$. Then you could choose e.g. $X=\mathbb R^2$ and the transformations
$$\begin{align}
A &= \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0}\\
B_1 &= \pmatrix{1 & 1\\0 & 1}\\
B_2 &= \pmatrix{2 & 0\\0 & 3}\\
C &= \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1\\0 & 0}
\end{align}$$
With that choice you'd get
$$\begin{align}
S &= \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0}\\
T &= \pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0}
\end{align}$$